# Unable to compile because of implicit conversions are ambiguous inside foreach

Tags: scala

My current problem is while dealing with field names inside `element` and `secondElement` variables, which happen to be BSONObject type objects.

```
val set        = element.keySet().union(secondElement.keySet())

set.foreach(key => {
            basicDbObject.put(key, getNumber(element, key) + getNumber(secondElement, key))

...
```

The way `getNumber` works is the following...

```
def getNumber(element: BSONObject, field: String): Long =
    if (element.containsField(field)) element.get(field).asInstanceOf[Long] else 0
```

But whenever I try to compile and run the code, the following error happens...

```
[error]  found   : Long
[error]  required: ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Long): ?}
[error] Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[error]  both method long2float in object Long of type (x: Long)Float
[error]  and method long2double in object Long of type (x: Long)Double
[error]  are possible conversion functions from Long to ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Long): ?}
[error]         basicDbObject.put(key, getNumber(element, key) + getNumber(secondElement, key))
```

And apart from the previous one, another one is shown telling me to check a type mismatch.

```
[error]  found   : Long
[error]  required: String
[error]         basicDbObject.put(key, getNumber(element, key) + getNumber(secondElement, key))
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you use `element.get(field).toFloat`?

Comment: @ElBaulP sadly no, everything which is inside a BSONObject is a plain Object that could be casted.

Comment: Could you post, as @DmytroMitin said, a MWE?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pattern matching works here:

Try to cast the value inside `match` and return it in case it is a instance of a `Long`.

```
def getNumber(element: BSONObject, field: String): Long =
    if (element.containsField(field)) 
        element.get(field) match {
           case x: Long => x
           case _ => // Default behaviour
        }
    else 0l
```

To understands what the error is trying to tell you:

```
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
[error]  both method long2float in object Long of type (x: Long)Float
[error]  and method long2double in object Long of type (x: Long)Double
[error]  are possible conversion functions from Long to ?{def +(x$1: ? >: Long): ?}
```

In `getNumber(element, key) + getNumber(secondElement, key)` you sometimes are returning a `Long` and other times a 0 (Which is an `Int`).